# Hibernate Search + Infinispan + S3 -- Prevent alphanumeric file names

Tags: hibernate, amazon-s3, hibernate-search, infinispan, jclouds

I'm looking for help in configuring Hibernate Search using Infinispan, storing the indexes on S3

Currently, it seems to be mostly working, but one of the index files it creates has an alphanumeric name, which comes back to throw the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LuceneIndexesMetadata-CloudCacheStore-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bucketId: A566834176 (expected: integer)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.bucket.Bucket.setBucketId(Bucket.java:77)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.cloud.CloudCacheStore.readFromBlob(CloudCacheStore.java:446)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.cloud.CloudCacheStore.scanBlobForExpiredEntries(CloudCacheStore.java:291)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.cloud.CloudCacheStore.purge(CloudCacheStore.java:283)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.cloud.CloudCacheStore.purgeInternal(CloudCacheStore.java:335)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.AbstractCacheStore$2.run(AbstractCacheStore.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

As a side note, enabling compression on the indexes causes a '.bz2' extension which throws this error on every index file.

I'm not sure where the problem lies. Should it only be creating index files with integer names? Is there a configuration item somewhere that will use a different read method that will allow alphanumeric names (and thus allow me to use compression)?

Maybe it's a version discrepancy. Here is a list of what I'm currently using:

Hibernate (core, entitymanager, search, search-infinispan): 4.2.0.Final
Infinispan (core, lucene-directory, cachestore-cloud): 5.1.8.Final
JClouds (core, blobstore, allblobstore, provider.aws-s3): 1.1.1

Here are a few of my configuration files:

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="###">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="infinispan"/> 
            <property name="hibernate.search.infinispan.configuration_resourcename" value="infinispan.xml"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

infinispan.xml

```
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.1 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.1.xsd" xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.1">


<!-- *************************** -->
<!-- System-wide global settings -->
<!-- *************************** -->
<global>
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" cacheManagerName="HibernateSearch" allowDuplicateDomains="true" />

    <transport clusterName="HibernateSearch-Infinispan-cluster" distributedSyncTimeout="30000">
        <properties>
            <property name="configurationFile" value="infinispan-s3.xml"/>
        </properties>
    </transport>

    <shutdown hookBehavior="REGISTER" />
</global>


<!-- *************************** -->
<!-- Default "template" settings -->
<!-- *************************** -->
<default>
    <locking lockAcquisitionTimeout="30000" writeSkewCheck="false" concurrencyLevel="500" useLockStriping="false" />

    <!-- Invocation batching is required for use with the Lucene Directory -->
    <invocationBatching enabled="true" />

    <clustering mode="invalidation">
        <!-- Prefer loading all data at startup than later -->
        <stateTransfer timeout="60000" fetchInMemoryState="false" />
        <!-- Network calls are synchronous by default -->
        <sync replTimeout="30000" />
    </clustering>
    <jmxStatistics enabled="false" />
    <eviction maxEntries="-1" strategy="NONE" />
    <expiration maxIdle="300000" />

<loaders passivation="false" shared="false" preload="true">
    <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.cloud.CloudCacheStore" fetchPersistentState="false" ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">
         <properties>
            <property name="identity" value="${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${AWS_SECRET_KEY}"/>
            <property name="bucketPrefix" value="${PARAM2}"/>
            <property name="cloudService" value="aws-s3"/>
            <property name="compress" value="false"/>
        </properties>
        <async
                   enabled="true"
                   flushLockTimeout="15000"
                   threadPoolSize="10"
        />
    </loader>
</loaders>

</default>

<!-- *************************************** -->
<!--  Cache to store Lucene's file metadata  -->
<!-- *************************************** -->
<namedCache
    name="LuceneIndexesMetadata">
    <clustering
        mode="invalidation">
        <stateTransfer
            fetchInMemoryState="false" />
        <!--<sync
            replTimeout="30000" /> -->
    </clustering>
</namedCache>

<!-- **************************** -->
<!--  Cache to store Lucene data  -->
<!-- **************************** -->
<namedCache
    name="LuceneIndexesData">
    <clustering
        mode="invalidation">
        <stateTransfer
            fetchInMemoryState="false" />
        <!--<sync
            replTimeout="30000" /> -->
    </clustering>
</namedCache>

<!-- ***************************** -->
<!--  Cache to store Lucene locks  -->
<!-- ***************************** -->
<namedCache
    name="LuceneIndexesLocking">
    <clustering
        mode="invalidation">
        <stateTransfer
            fetchInMemoryState="false" />
        <!--<sync
            replTimeout="30000" /> -->
    </clustering>
</namedCache>
```

Any help in getting this correctly configured would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I know what is going on, but still don't know how to resolve the issue.

Hibernate Search, or Lucene, is creating files with a leading '-', such as '-566834176'. When the file gets put up to S3, it is converting the '-' to an 'A', i.e. 'A566834176'.

Can anyone shed light on how to prevent the negative number index file names?

Comment: Hi, neither Lucene nor Hibernate Search create such files: Infinispan uses numeric bucket ids, and that seems to be a problem with the JClouds integration. Please file an issue here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN

Comment: @DaveV we're you ever able to resolve this issue? If so, what did you have to do to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Neither *Apache Lucene* nor *Hibernate Search* create such files: *Infinispan* uses numeric bucket ids, and depending on the value hashing of these buckets some might be in the negative space: that seems to be a problem with the JClouds integration.

Please file an issue here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN